# Xcode Passing buttons from one uiview to another(Storyboard)

Tags: ipad, xcode-storyboard, xcode4.6.3

On a viewcontroller I want to create a *uiscrollview* with multiple buttons and I want to be able to choose only 1 to 4 buttons and pass them to another *uiview* and then send them to another *viewcontroller*. I'm guessing it should be on a uiview+animation category? (It's on an iPad btw). Unfortunately stackoverflow doesn't let me to upload a picture but I hope I made it clear.

Comment: What's your actual question? (Or are you expecting people to code this for you, or ?)

Comment: Don't pass UI elements, pass data that represents your choice to the other view controller and let it react as needed.  The UI shouldn't be a place for storing state or business logic.